# Python: Counting a specific set of character occurrences in lines of a file

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am struggling with a small program in Python which aims at counting the occurrences of a specific set of characters in the lines of a text file.

As an example, if I want to count '!' and '@' from the following lines

```
hi!
hello@gmail.com
collection!
```

I'd expect the following output:

```
!;2
@;1
```

So far I got a functional code, but it's inefficient and does not use the potential that Python libraries have.
I have tried using collections.counter, with limited success. The efficiency blocker I found is that I couldn't select specific sets of characters on counter.update(), all the rest of the characters found were also counted. Then I would have to filter the characters I am not interested in, which adds another loop...
I also considered regular expressions, but I can't see an advantage in this case.

This is the functional code I have right now (the simplest idea I could imagine), which looks for special characters in file's lines. I'd like to see if someone can come up with a neater Python-specific idea:

```
 def count_special_chars(filename):
      special_chars = list('!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ ')
      dict_count = dict(zip(special_chars, [0] * len(special_chars)))

      with open(filename) as f:
          for passw in f:
              for c in passw:
                  if c in special_chars:
                      dict_count[c] += 1
      return dict_count
```

thanks for checking

Comment: You can avoid that slash-escaped quote by using triple-quotes for the string… see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminating the extra counts from `collections.Counter` is probably not significant either way, but if it bothers you, do it during the initial iteration:

```
from collections import Counter
special_chars = '''!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ '''
found_chars = [c for c in open(yourfile).read() if c in special_chars]
counted_chars = Counter(found_chars)
```

Comment: In this case I miss having the detailed output per each character. But I take note on the efficiency

Comment: What detailed output? You can still use pprint on a Counter, and for every character _not_ there you can be sure the count is zero.

Comment: true, sorry that I overlooked that

Answer (score 3):

Why not count the whole file all together? You should avoid looping through string for each line of the file. Use string.count instead.

```
from pprint import pprint

# Better coding style: put constant out of the function
SPECIAL_CHARS = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ '

def count_special_chars(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.read()
        return dict([(i, content.count(i)) for i in SPECIAL_CHARS])

pprint(count_special_chars('example.txt'))
```

example output:

```
{' ': 0,
 '!': 2,
 '.': 1,
 '@': 1,
 '[': 0,
 '~': 0
 # the remaining keys with a value of zero are ignored
  ...}
```

Comment: thanks! this looks great.
I just checked execution times:
--- 0.0005624294281005859 seconds ---
--- 0.00032973289489746094 seconds _new_proposed_zyxue---

I have an additional consideration, that I didn't want to include in the original request to avoid extra complication:

what if I wanted to count only one occurrence per word? such as:
!!aaa!! 
gives
!;1

Comment: But this is actually looping quite a bit - each content.count is searching the entire string, one time for every character in special_chars.

Comment: testing it with my file, your solution kojiro is slightly faster,

--- 0.00044918060302734375 seconds ---
--- 0.0002338886260986328 seconds _new_proposed_zyxue---
--- 0.00020933151245117188 seconds _new_kojiro---

I am only counting the execution of count_special_chars(filename)

Comment: kojiro is right, my solution loops as many times as the number of special characters. To take care of cases like !!aaa!!, depending on how you define a word (by space?) and they look like (more examples?), you could use split and then regex to replace continuous special characters first before counting.

Answer (score 1):

- need not to process file contents line-by-line
- to avoid nested loops, which increase complexity of your program

  - If you want to count character occurrences in some string, first, you loop over the entire string to construct an occurrence dict. Then, you can find any occurrence of character from the dict. This reduce complexity of the program.

    - When constructing occurrence dict, defaultdict would help you to initialize count values.

A refactored version of the program is as below:

```
special_chars = list('!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ ')
dict_count = defaultdict(int)

with open(filename) as f:
    for c in f.read():
        dict_count[c] += 1

for c in special_chars:
    print('{0};{1}'.format(c, dict_count[c]))
```

ref. defaultdict Examples: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this where you do not need to use the counter library. I used it to count all the special char but you can adapt to put the count in a dict.

```
import re

def countSpecial(passwd):
    specialcount = 0
    for special in special_chars:
        lenght = 0
        #print special
        lenght = len(re.findall(r'(\%s)' %special , passwd))
        if lenght > 0:
            #print lenght,special
            specialcount = lenght + specialcount
    return specialcount
```